# Matlab- anomalous fft2 display

Tags: matlab, fft

I'm trying to plot a 2D fft of a simple image in matlab, however the resulting plot looks very strange and unlike any 2D fft plots I have encountered so far. It is mostly white, with a few grid-like dotted black lines.

this is the code for the plot I'm trying to obtain:

```
fftA = fftshift(fft2(digimageA));
imshow((abs(fftA)))
```

Any comments would be very helpful, thanks.

I'll also post the code relating to the generation of the image:

```
m = 501; n = 501;
digimageA = zeros(m, n);

for i = 1:size(digimageA, 1)
    for j = 1:size(digimageA, 2)

        if (i <= round(m/2) + 20)&&(i >= round(m/2) - 20)&&(j <= round(n/2) + 20)&&(j >= round(n/2) - 20)

            digimageA(i,j) = 255;
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`imshow`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html) with `double` input expect values to be between `0` and `1`. Values above `1` are clipped to `1`, and so the shown image is incorrect.

To auto-scale the range of represented values, use either

```
imshow(abs(fftA), [])
```

or

```
imagesc((abs(fftA)))
```

Comment: It seems to have done the trick, I was unaware of the clipping happening. Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: Yes, `imshow`'s documentation is not terribly clear on that